# Deploying telegram bot with heruko problem

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot

My problem's in the final stage of the deploying process,

when i click deploy branch, it says ther's an error like the following:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement email-tp==0.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for email-tp==0.1.0**

requirements.txt file contain:

python-telegram-bot

secure-smtplib

email-to == 0.1.0

ssl

the problem happens with email-to and ssl packages

can any one help me with that please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo in your `requirements.txt`. As the error says, you're trying to install `email-tp==0.1.0` instead of `email-to==0.1.0`.

As a tip, you may want to freeze your projects using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to avoid this kind of complications.